# How to rate limit a Heroku Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rate-limiting

I built a app on Heroku in Rails, and someone wrote a bot to do a GET on my website over and over. Is there a way I can stop them from doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through rack middleware. Take a look at https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack